# Ordering x-axis when combining plot types

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm combining a boxplot and a dot plot using ggplot and would like to order the x-axis so that the boxplots are next to each other.

Reordering the factors to the desired order does not work as `ggplot` calls `fortify` on the data and removes the unused factors when I pass data to `geom_boxplot` or `geom_point`.

Here's an example.

```
set.seed(100)
x<-factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3],5)) 
y<-runif(15,0,10) 

data<-data.frame(x=x,y=y) 

data$x <- factor(data$x,levels=c("A","C","B"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+
        geom_boxplot(data=data[data$x %in% c("A","C"),])+
        geom_point(data=data[data$x=="B",])
```

[image: ggplot plot]

The desired output would be the A and C boxplots next to each other, followed by the B dot plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `scale_x_discrete()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+
  geom_boxplot(data=data[data$x %in% c("A","C"),])+
  geom_point(data=data[data$x=="B",]) +
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c("A", "C", "B"))
```

[image]